# Bitbucket: HTTP/2 stream 5 was not closed cleanly before end of the underlying stream

Tags: git, bitbucket

When trying to push to git using: `git push`, I all of a sudden get the following error message:

`fatal: unable to access 'https://bitbucket.org/mopla-solutions/mopla-server.git/': HTTP/2 stream 5 was not closed cleanly before end of the underlying stream`

I tried the following things recommended in various SO answers and other sites:

- changing to another network (mobile hotspot)
- setting git config: `git config --global http.version HTTP/1.1` and `git config --global http.postBuffer 524288000`

But so far, nothing helped. Is there any other way I can debug this issue?

**UPDATE:** Bitbucket has resolved this issue - everything is working normally now.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The bitbucket API is experiencing a partial outage. Track on their status page https://bitbucket.status.atlassian.com/incidents/3308g2hlkfsx

Comment: joyfully, issue has been fixed by bitbucket

Answer (score 9):

It's a bitbucket system error you have to wait until they fix it

Answer (score 4):

Great, it's something general, I do have the same issue these last 30 minutes.

They are working on a solution.

Bitbucket website and API partial outage
Investigating - We are investigating reports of intermittent errors for all Atlassian Bitbucket Cloud customers. We will provide more details once we identify the root cause.
Sep 25, 2022 - 15:49 UTC

Answer (score 1):

BitBucket is aware of the problem : "Bitbucket website and API partial outage"

https://bitbucket.status.atlassian.com/